# Listbox not showing all items from local database on WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have declared DataTemplate as

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FuelUpsListBoxTemplate">

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="780" ShowGridLines="True" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Name="b1" Background="GreenYellow">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Aqua"
                                Text="{Binding FillUpDate}" 
                                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" 
                                Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="4, 4, 4, 4"/>
                </Border>

            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding Oddomer}" 
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" 
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-36, 12, 0, 0"/>

            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding Fuel}" 
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" 
                Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-36, 12, 0, 0"/>

            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding Price}" 
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" 
                Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-36, 12, 0, 0"/>

            <CheckBox 
                IsChecked="{Binding FullTank, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

and use it in xaml listbox:

```
                    <StackPanel Height="535" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0">
                        <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" 
                        Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding FillUpItems}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FuelUpsListBoxTemplate}" 
                        Hold="MainListBox_Hold" />
                    </StackPanel></grid>.....
```

When  i execute app, only 9 items from database are shown, even when it contains 20-30 items...

Here's also code from viewmodel that select data from database.

```
        var FillUpsinDB = from FillupItem todo in CarLogDB.FillUps
                            select todo;
        FillUpItems = new ObservableCollection<FillupItem>(FillUpsinDB);
```

When i inspect "todo"  variable, debugger says that it contain all items in db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because your StackPanel has fixed Height (535).

btw: Why is your ListBox wrapped in StackPanel? Is it neccessary?

Comment: That's it... problem got fixed when i set <ListBox Height="536">.... And StackPanel is necessary because i have few more controls on same page. Thanks for answer...